# Run an NXT 2 program that will continue until no power is left in batteries

Tags: nxt

I want to run an NXT 2 program that will continue until no power is left in batteries. I want it to rotate slowly so that a sculpture can be turned for as long as possible. It seems to go for a few hour then shuts down.

Comment: If all you're doing is rotating something, could you just do it with a regular power functions motor? It will definitely run until it overheats or drains the batteries.

Comment: The NXT has a feature to turn itself of after a period of inactivity. Somewhere in the menus on it you can turn that off. I don't remember where it was, by it wasn't hard to find.

Comment: Regarding using regular power functions, they are too fast in my experience. Using gear reduction is possible, but the parts will wear down. Using voltage regulation is imprecise and I think that besides running slower, the motor applies also less torque.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Keep Alive Block** in your program.

[image]

> This block will keep the NXT from entering sleep mode. Add this block
>   if your program needs to wait for longer than the NXTs set "sleep
>   time" (configured using the NXTs on-board menus).

The *Time until sleep* plug will take a value from 0 - 4294967296 (16<sup>8</sup>) milliseconds .

4294967296 milliseconds is just over 49 days which is most likely a lot longer than the battery lifespan and much, much longer then you would/should normally be running it for.

Comment: As Ambo100 suggested, use the Keep Alive Block. Keep in mind though, that many batteries don't like getting drained completely. If you're using rechargeable batteries, this might damage them. It's been a while since I used NXT-G code, so I can't remember if there's a block that let's you check the current status of the batteries.